# Eclipse (Oxygen), Run/Debug Bar disappears when switching Java/XML Files

Tags: java, eclipse

May be the question is already out there, but I really have no idea how to search for it. At least my attempts were unsuccessful.

I've installed Eclipse Oxygen. And when I've open a Java Class and a configuration File (eg. application.properties), the Toolbar for Run/Debug hides when I'm not in the Java File.

This is quite annoying if you have several classes open and you only want to change one setting in the configuration and then just want to start the application. At the moment I have to switch back to any Java class to use the toolbar or to make it visible again.

The whole keyboard shortcuts are too wild and nested for me...

Is there any setting to make this run/debug toolbar sticky?

Thanks a lot,

Tom

Comment: Do you mean the _Debug_ and the _Run_ buttons in the main toolbar (or the CDT launch bar)? These buttons are only shown permanently in some perspectives, e. g. the Java Perspective (_Window > Perspective > Open Perspective_).

Comment: THANK YOU! Oh man. I was in the resource Perspective... *shakinghead* Thought eclipse takes the same settings from my workspace setting. Layout : yes... Perspective : seems not!  Thanks a lot

Comment: Great. I added the solution as an answer in case somebody else has the same problem (the perspective concept is not very intuitive).

Answer (score 1):

The visibility of the main toolbar items is bound to the editor and to the perspective. **Make sure, you are in the *Java* or *Debug* perspective** and not in the *Resource* or *Git* perspective:

***Window > Window > Perspective > Open Perspective > Java***